# JUnit Test to test conversion of primitive to wrapper class

Tags: java, junit

What is the best way to unit test conversion of primitive to a Wrapper.
I have written where i pass an array of ints and get back an array of Integers. I know  I could use ClassUtils.isPrimitiveOrWrapper() to check if its a primitive or wrapper but is there another way to do this without using external dependency.

Thanks

Comment: The codebase of `ClassUtils.isPrimitiveOrWrapper()` isn't actually too complex or large. [Perhaps extract what you need from it and adapt it to your case?](https://github.com/apache/commons-lang/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/ClassUtils.java#L707)

Comment: With question wording like that, do you actually want to test that primitive types are converted to wrapper types correctly? Are you writing suites for JVMs?

Answer (score 3):

`ClassUtils.isPrimitiveOrWrapper()` checks whether a class is a primitive or a wrapper.
And you want to test if the array of `Integer` was correctly mapped to an array of  `int`.
It will not really help you.
What you need in your test is asserting that each `Integer` was correctly mapped into the corresponding `int` value and in the correct order.

For example :

```
Integer[] fixtureIntegers = new Integer[]{Integer.valueOf(1), Integer.valueOf(2), Integer.valueOf(2)};
int[] mappedInts = myClassUnderTest.map(fixtureIntegers);

// First : assert equality size
Assert.assertEquals(fixtureIntegers.length, mappedInts.length);

// Second : assert content 
for (int i=0; i<fixtureIntegers.length; i++)
    Assert.assertEquals(fixtureIntegers[i], mappedInts[i]);
}
```

Of course if `Integer` elements may be `null` in the original array, you have also to handle this case in the assertion.

Comment: Thaks a lot David. This is what i was I was aiming to do.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [guava's Ints.asList()](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#asList-int...-)